# How to prevent CGI program from loading large modules every time?

Tags: php, r, apache, web

I am writing a web application that will call an R script frequently.
This R script uses the package gRain, which takes a lot of time to be loaded. And the user has 
to wait a long time.

I am using a regular Apache server and PHP 5.

Ideally, I would like all the modules to be loaded once on the server, not every time the R script is called. Is there anyway I could solve this problem?

I searched over but didn't found any discussion (I believe this is a popular issue and maybe I did not find a good key word)
Really appreciate any suggestions. If my question is not very clear, please comment. Thanks!

Comment: How do you execute your R script?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Something like this:<form name=\"cgiform\" id=\"cgiform\" action=\"/cgi-bin/name.r\" method=\"post\">         the   R script is under the CGI folder. When the form is submitted, it gets executed.

Comment: This is a known downside to CGI. There are some alternatives like FastCGI, but I've never seen any R implementations. You could look into doing this yourself if you're determined.

Comment: hm..it was just a prototype so I did not spend time on the web structure. Is there anyway to preload the packages to memory and would that work?

Comment: Not with CGI, no. A new process is started for each request. The principle behind FastCGI and, for example, mod_perl and mod_php, is that a process persists in the background, so that there is no waiting for an application to start up.